# Ruby: How to append unique values to duplicates? E.g (value, value_2, value_3)

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I'm using software that won't allow duplicate values for the field "Node_ID", the nodes are a collection of objects with multiple fields (e.g X co-ordinate, Y co-ordinate, elevation). I am looking to rename the Node_Ids for all the nodes to a new format, but struggling to append a unique number for any duplicates encountered.

Based on other threads I've read, I have tried to located any duplicates using the following:

```
array.include?(node)

duplicates = array.select{|element| array.count(element) > 1}
```

I'm at a point where the code appears to recognise a duplicate and appends "_1" to the duplicate node, however if there is yet another duplicate it also appends "_1"...

```
$array = Array.new    # this is a temporary array I have been using to store the written Node_IDs, to check against for duplicates.
xy_nodes = ('_nodes').each do |xy|
    x1 = xy.x.to_i
    y1 = xy.y.to_i
    x = x1.to_s.rjust(7, "0")
    y = y1.to_s.rjust(7, "0")
    node = x+y
        # the above was just getting it to the correct format, no issues there
    if $array.include?(node)
        i=0
        node = node + "_#{i+1}"    # this is where things need sorted, clearly as it stands this would only result in _1 being added for the duplicates, however I'm struggling to iterate and check against duplicates after the first to continue adding _1, _2, _3 as suffixes.
        $array << node
        $checkmsg << node    # this array is used later
        xy.user_text = node    # used for writing to as this field can accept duplicates
        xy.write
    else
        puts "...iteration found no duplicates"
        $array << node
        xy.user_text = node
        xy.write        
    end
    puts "************ END OF ITERATION **************"
    puts ""
end
```

This results in something similar to below (in "user_text" field):

```
05555550333333
04444440222222
05555550333333_1
05555550333333_1
```

Just wondering how best to get the code to assess the new duplicate and count upward for each one found and get:

```
05555550333333
04444440222222
05555550333333_1
05555550333333_2
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE: In response to answers**

I was having trouble squeezing in info to the comments so I thought I'd write here. First off, thanks for answering so far. All three techniques appear to work well in making $array look what I'm hoping for the finished article of the Node_IDs (or user_text whilst testing) to be.

For example, using these methods I'm able to get the $array output:

```
02511160678961
02735510688965
02966900697649
03216480682699
02735510688965_1
02735510688965_2
02735510688965_3
03355411149097
```

However, the $array in my code was originally just used as something I was throwing "node" into, in order to check against to see if it had been used before, rather than being an array I wanted to format/write itself.

Each node is an object within the table ('_nodes'). And I'm hoping to iteratively write the new user_text (Node_ID) checking for duplicates each iteration, rather than at the end of a completed array.

My aim was to update each object's user_text (eventually Node_ID once solved) and add it to the $array for checking for duplicates when the next object's user_text is going to be written. Not sure if there is an obvious way to apply the suggestions so far to each object before writing - rather than to a completed array like I have managed with your help.

Also not sure if I am being entirely clear - please ask if not and I can edit my initial post further. Also happy to abandon my initial thought process if it seems like its the wrong train of thought.  Thanks again.

Comment: `'_nodes'` is a string. Strings don't have a method `each`, so `('_nodes').each` will raise a no-method exception. All of us giving answers assumed that strings were contained in an array. Your edit suggests otherwise, but you haven't told us where they are coming from. Are they being returned one at a time by some unstated method, being read from a file, or what? As an aside, it's almost never a good idea to use global variables, except perhaps when debugging.

Comment: As per engineersmnky's question: ('_node') is referring to a table within a database that I'm editing - should have made this clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach makes a single pass through the array and maintains order.

```
names = ['21_1', '34', '49_2', '21_1', '21_1', '49_2', '14_2']

nxt_hash = {}
names.map do |name|
  next name unless name.include?('_')
  prefix, _, suffix = name.partition('_')
  nxt = nxt_hash[name] || suffix.to_i
  nxt_hash[name] = nxt + 1
  "%s_%d" % [prefix, nxt]
end
  #=> ["21_1", "34", "49_2", "21_2", "21_3", "49_3", "14_2"]
```

When finished,

```
nxt_hash
  #=> {"21_1"=>4, "49_2"=>4, "14_2"=>3}
```

This approach would be modified ever-so-slightly if you are processing strings one-at-a-time, as you would if you were reading from a file or a database, or they were being returned individually by a method.

Let's define an enumerator that will generate names one at a time.

```
enum = names.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["21_1", "34", "49_2", "21_1", "21_1", "49_2", "14_2"]:each>
```

Then

```
enum.next  #=> "21_1" 
enum.next  #=> "34" 
enum.next  #=> "49_2" 
enum.next  #=> "21_1" 
enum.next  #=> "21_1" 
enum.next  #=> "49_2" 
enum.next  #=> "14_2" 
enum.next  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

and so on. We can now build the desired array (`arr`) as follows.

```
enum = names.to_enum
arr = []
nxt_hash = {}
loop do
  name = enum.next
  unless name.include?('_')
    arr << name
    next
  end
  prefix, _, suffix = name.partition('_')
  nxt = nxt_hash[name] || suffix.to_i
  nxt_hash[name] = nxt + 1
  arr << "%s_%d" % [prefix, nxt]
end
arr
  #=> ["21_1", "34", "49_2", "21_2", "21_3", "49_3", "14_2"]
```

Here `enum.next` (see [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)) returns a `StopIteration` exception when it has no more elements to generate. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles that expression by breaking out of the loop. If each `name` is supplied by a method or forms a line that is read from a file or database, you will have other ways of breaking out of the loop, but my use of an enumerator simulates all ways of generating `name`s one at a time.

This approach can modified to address a more general problem.

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e']

nxt_hash = {}
names.map do |name|
  nxt = nxt_hash[name]
  nxt_hash[name] = nxt.to_i + 1
  nxt.nil? ? name : "%s_%s" % [name, nxt]
end
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "a_1", "a_2", "c_1", "b_1", "e"]
```

When finished,

```
nxt_hash
  #=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>2, "e"=>1}
```

Note: `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your input - another useful technique which definitely looks promising. I was having a bit of an issue with the word count so I have updated my initial post at the bottom for further elaboration/queries!

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, I'll have a look into it in the morning - assuming my other comment doesn't have an effect on it!

Answer (score 2):

Different twists on the same concept posted by @iGian

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e']

names.group_by(&:itself).flat_map do |k,v| 
  v.size.times.map {|n| n.zero? ? k : "#{k}_#{n}"}
end
```

The sort order will change based on the occurrence of unique elements in the list

OR

```
names.sort.chunk_while {|a,b| a == b }.flat_map do |a| 
  a.map.with_index {|b,idx| idx.zero? ? b : "#{b}_#{idx}"}
end
```

The sort order will change based on natural sorting of the element list.

Comment: I like `.group_by(&:itself)`, which is also the fastest.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response - definitely useful. I have updated my original post at the bottom to elaborate further and enquire more.

Comment: @Ryan when you say "table" are you referring to a database? This could be alot simpler if so.

Comment: Yes ('_node') is referring to a table within a database that I'm editing - should have made this clearer!

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, maybe can help.

Let's say this is your array of `names`:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

This is one option to rename the elements:

```
tmp = names.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
#=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>2, "e"=>1}
```

So basically it counts the element and generates the hash above. Then map the hash to rebuild the array appending the variation:

```
tmp.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), a| a << ([k]*v).map.with_index { |e, i| e + "_#{i}" }  }
#=> [["a_0", "a_1", "a_2"], ["b_0", "b_1"], ["c_0", "c_1"], ["e_0"]]
```

Of course, you can skip appending the index if `v == 1`:

```
{ |e, i| v == 1 ? e : e + "_#{i}" }
```

The methods used are explained here: [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html), [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html), [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html)

---

The second part can be refactored to:

```
tmp.flat_map { |k, v| v.times.map { |i| v == 1 ? k : k + "_#{i}" } }
#=> ["a_0", "a_1", "a_2", "b_0", "b_1", "c_0", "c_1", "e"]
```

And a one liner, just for fun:

```
names.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }.flat_map { |k, v| v.times.map { |i| v == 1 ? k : k + "_#{i}" } }
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. All the responses so far have been helpful - I have updated my original post at the bottom to elaborate further and enquire more if you have a moment!